# How to calculate a cell reference in google sheets?

Tags: arrays, reference, google-sheets

I'm trying to use a sheet array reference, for example `Sheet1!C2:C10`, in a filter function in Sheet2 to reference an array in Sheet1 that changes in length from day to day. So, the C10 reference above is actually variable from day to day.

So, the array is in Sheet1 in column C2 down to where ever, growing longer day by day until some point where data collection stops. The array is generated by a form which writes row by row with a time stamp in column A. The reference is used in Sheet2 in a filter function.

So, I'm thinking I should try something like 
`Sheet1!C2:indirect("C" & counta(Sheet1!A:A))`

But, it doesn't work. And it produces `ERROR: FILTER has mismatched range sizes. Expected row count: 9. column count: 1. Actual row count: 1, column count: 1.`

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know what you are trying to filter, but try this:

```
=filter(arrayformula(Sheet1!C2:C),Sheet1!C2:C<>"")
```

Change the filter to your need.